# Was the name mArIcha (मारीच), a demon in Raamayana, adopted from the word marīcikā (मरीचिका)?

Tags: ramayana, sanskrit

marīcikā (मरीचिका) means mirage.

https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/?q=mar%C4%ABcik%C4%81&iencoding=deva&lang=sans&action=Search

**Mirage** means *an unrealistic hope or wish that cannot be achieved or illusory appearance of water in a desert*

---

Mirage is an illusion. My doubt is whether the name **mArIcha** (मारीच), a demon in Raamayana, adopted by Sage Valmiki  from the word **marīcikā** (मरीचिका), for indicating his character as an illusion?

Comment: What makes you think so?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma: Mirage is an illusion.  And, the Sage Valmiki might have adopted the name mArIcha, whose form as a deer is an illusion.  That is my guessing.